# assertj how to check in a list that a property is greather than a value

Tags: assertj

Given:

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} 

List<Point> points;
```

How can I check that property x in a list of Points is greather than a value? I aim something similar to:

```
assertThat(points).extracting("x").isGreatherThan(20)
```

However I can't find 'isGreatherThan' after 'extracting'

**Update**

I don't aim writing custom conditions for this kind of value checking, as assertj already has methods for checking numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filteredOn` as it supports java 8 `Predicate`, e.g:

```
assertThat(listOfPoints).filteredOn(p -> p.x > 20).isNotEmpty();
```

If you want to do more complex stuff, using `Condition` is the way to go, in AssertJ 3.x they are simpler to write, rewriting Florian Schaetz example:

```
Condition<Integer> greaterThan20 = new Condition<>(v -> v.intValue() > 20, "greater than 20");
```

Comment: thanks, but Lambdas are custom conditions. My question is if somehow I can use assertj assertions such as isGreaterThan to check numbers in a list

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one...

```
.extracting( "x", Integer.class ).areAtLeast( 1, greaterThan20 );
```

Of course you'll have to [write the condition yourself](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html), something like...

```
final Condition<Integer> greaterThan20 = new Condition<Integer>("greater than 20") {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(Integer value) {
    return value.intValue() > 20;
  }
};
```

Comment: I was looking for solution without custom conditions

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you can do something like this:

```
assertThat(listOfPoints.stream().filter(p->p.x > 20).toArray()).hasSameSizeAs(listOfPoints);
```

That's for the case where you want ALL points to have x > 20.

To verify that there's at least one (as in Florian Schaetz's answer):

```
assertThat(listOfPoints.stream().filter(p->p.x > 20).toArray()).isNotEmpty();
```

Comment: Good idea, didn't think of Java 8's streams as a possibility.

Comment: thanks, but  Lambdas are custom conditions. My question is if somehow I can use assertj assertions such as isGreaterThan to check numbers in a list.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a really old post, but I was needing the answer and it took me forever to find it.  Please find the answer below.

```
import lombok.Builder;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactories;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;

public class StreamThePointsThenCheckEachXIndividually {

  @Builder
  record Point(int x, int y) {}

  @Test
  void extractingToIntegerInstance() {

    var points = List.of(
      Point.builder().x(1).y(2).build(),
      Point.builder().x(5).y(25).build(),
      Point.builder().x(3).y(16).build(),
      Point.builder().x(58).y(0).build()
    );

    points.forEach(point -> Assertions.assertThat(point)
      .extracting(Point::x)
      .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.INTEGER)
      .as("point %s", point.x())
      .isGreaterThan(0));
  }
}
```